# Tensorflow: 'module' object has no attribute 'FixedLenFeature'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was running through Google's Tensorflow's fully_connected_reader.py example (I have executed convert_to_record.py, and source code is here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data):

```
python fully_connected_reader.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.6.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:101] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.0 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fully_connected_reader.py", line 198, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "fully_connected_reader.py", line 194, in main
    run_training()
  File "fully_connected_reader.py", line 135, in run_training
    num_epochs=FLAGS.num_epochs)
  File "fully_connected_reader.py", line 114, in inputs
    image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)
  File "fully_connected_reader.py", line 62, in read_and_decode
    'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FixedLenFeature'
```

Anyone got any idea?   (it is running from the latest github version).

Comment: Can you provide more code how you're importing `tf`?

Comment: thank you woozyking, i have updated above with the link to the python script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using TensorFlow 2.x, FixedLenFeature has moved from `tf.FixedLenFeature` into `tf.io.FixedLenFeature`.

The use of `tf.FixedLenFeature` was marked as deprecated in previous versions.

Answer (score 4):

`FixedLenFeature` was [added](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/492e55ff2297dc13f5ed540056ad40603f2b1dd0) in [TensorFlow 0.7.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v0.7.0). You have an earlier version installed. You can check your version with `print tf.__version__`.

Comment: you are right, mine is "0.6".   I thought updating the tensorflow through github + running configure will update the tensorflow installation.   But it seemed tensorflow installation is separately installed as per here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.io.FixedLenFeature` instead. Same goes for `VarLenFeature` (use `tf.io.VarLenFeature`).